# include new line/crlf into string variable using expression builder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, power-automate

I am building a flow, and need to append values into a string variable for an audit trail

so I have this:

```
concat(string(utcNow()), ': ', 'Approved by Data Protection', Char(13))
```

but I get an error when trying to save the expression ...

in the list following the update (using the variable) it looks like this:

```
2019-05-21T08:28:43.2692428Z: Approved by Health & Safety2019-05-21T08:30:02.4883027Z: Approved by Data Protection
```

when it should look like this:

```
2019-05-21T08:28:43.2692428Z: Approved by Health & Safety
2019-05-21T08:30:02.4883027Z: Approved by Data Protection
```

what am I doing wrong, and how can I include a new line/line feed into the variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple and neat resolution is to initialize a new `String` Variable and just type ENTER key inside `Value` input.

Or just put `\n` in `concat()` function.

[image]